# Spring Boot OAuth2 with Github

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing OAuth2 architecture with GitHub as authorization server to log into my dummy web application. Everything works perfectly fine. I got problem when I log in using my GitHub credentials I want the redirected page to show some message for user for example Welcome XYZ, but I could not get username who is logged in currently but a number is shown instead. I used principal object as well as Authentication object. Please would any body tell how do I achieve it?

Here is code for OAuth2 GitHub Configuration.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.oauth2.client.CommonOAuth2Provider;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapterImp extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2Login((c)->
        {
        c.clientRegistrationRepository(this.clientRegistrationRepository());    
        }
        );
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        
    }
    
    
    private  ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository()
    {
        ClientRegistration c=this.clientRegistration(); 
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(c);
    }
    
    private ClientRegistration clientRegistration()
    {
        return CommonOAuth2Provider.GITHUB.getBuilder("github").clientId("72bc31d8b0304575442c").clientSecret("XYZSECRET").build();
    }
}
```

Code for main_controller to which user will be redirected after logging in.

```
package com.controllers;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class Main_Controller {

    @GetMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String HomePage(Authentication p)
    {
        System.out.println("Hellow  "+p.getName());
        return "Hello People.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default if you use "CommonOAuth2Provider.GITHUB" then principal name is map to "id" of your github user. So, you need to map principal name attribute to "login"

Comment: Sure. We can also use OAuth2authentication to get OAuth2User. Then we can simply retrieve username.